# javascript line-width for <table>?

Tags: javascript

I made a table but I don't want the rows to stretch as much and I want them to accurately frame the rows (currently there is a lot of empty space after the text). Would appreciate a clarification!

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>"0, 0"</td>
    <td>"0, 1"</td>
    <td>"0, 2"</td>
    <td>"0, 3"</td>
    <td>"0, 4"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"1, 0"</td>
    <td>"1, 1"</td>
    <td>"1, 2"</td>
    <td>"1, 3"</td>
    <td>"1, 4"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"2, 0"</td>
    <td>"2, 1"</td>
    <td>"2, 2"</td>
    <td>"2, 3"</td>
    <td>"2, 4"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"3, 0"</td>
    <td>"3, 1"</td>
    <td>"3, 2"</td>
    <td>"3, 3"</td>
    <td>"3, 4"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"4, 0"</td>
    <td>"4, 1"</td>
    <td>"4, 2"</td>
    <td>"4, 3"</td>
    <td>"4, 4"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by  `I don't want the rows to stretch as much` ? or `currently there is a lot of empty space after the text` ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Interestingly enough it doesn't occur when I run the code snippet here on Stackoverflow, but when I refresh my page, there is a big empty space to the right of each and every text within each and every cell, meaning the entire table is not one symmetrical 'square', but rather it stretches to the right.

Comment: Then it may be because of context we don't have, e.g., additional CSS, the real content, etc.

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [Minimal and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yeah I'd wager you're using Bootstrap or some such that is forcing the table to 100% width. Add some definitions to the td and table CSS will help. Probably just table {width: auto; }. No need for javascript, I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `width` CSS property for `table, tr, td` and set it to `auto`. This would auto resize the width as per the content.

JavaScript isn't actually necessary to achieve this behaviour. However, if you really wish to use it, you can assign different `classes` to  `table, tr & td` respectively and set their widths as shown:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('your-class-name').width = 'auto';
```